# How to add text over GIF animation?

Tags: animated-gif, caption

I have a gif animation and I want to add a caption over it. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.online-image-editor.com/
Seems to do the job - I tested it roughly. Even has lolcats-text function :)

Comment: I was looking for exactly that and for that very purpose :) thanks

Comment: Now I just need to compress the gif before sending it to the server (it's 13 Megs).

Comment: Try an optimizer like http://ezgif.com or https://compressor.io/
They work on animated GIFs also. They are lossy so you may notice slight degradation of image quality (I noticed more with Compressor than EZGIF). With your huge 13MB file size, hopefully it will really cut it down.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `convert`, which is part of imageMagick:

`convert -annotate +x+y "text" animation.gif`

where `x` and `y` are numbers indicating the coordinates of the text where the origin is the top left hand corner of the image.

Comment: You may need to specify `-font <FONT-NAME or FONT-FILE>` to display non-ASCII characters.

Answer (score 0):

Opening animated .gif in Photoshop creates a layer for each frame. You can add text to those layers and and save back.

Comment: There are 190+ frames. Is there a way to quickly apply the same caption to all layers ?

Comment: In photoshop case you should use "Actions" for automating.